# Unbounded wildcards with extends and super as parameters

Tags: java, generics

Help me please to undestand why i can't call the testSuper() method? There is compile error:

```
The method testSuper(Group<? super BClass<?>>) in the type Group <BClass<String>> is not applicable for the arguments (Group<AClass<String>>)
```

But the testExtends() method OK. However, it looks the same.

```
class AClass<T> {}

class BClass<T> extends AClass<T> {}

class Group<T> {
    T name;
    public void testExtends(Group<? extends AClass<?>> value){} 
    public void testSuper(Group<? super BClass<?>> value){}
    public T getName(){return name;}
}

public class GenericTest {

    public static void GenericTestMethod(){

        Group<AClass<String>> instGrA = new Group<AClass<String>>();
        Group<BClass<String>> instGrB = new Group<BClass<String>>();

        //OK
        instGrA.testExtends(instGrB);

        //The method testSuper(Group<? super BClass<?>>) in the type Group <BClass<String>>
        //is not applicable for the arguments (Group<AClass<String>>)
        instGrB.testSuper(instGrA);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a difference between the calls.

In the call that compiles,

```
instGrA.testExtends(instGrB);
```

you pass a `Group<BClass<String>>` to a method that is expecting a `Group<? extends AClass<?>>`.  That matches, because `BClass<String>` is a subtype of `AClass<?>>` -- `BClass` is a subclass of `AClass`, and `String` is a subtype of `?`.

However, in the call that doesn't compile,

```
instGrB.testSuper(instGrA);
```

you pass a `Group<AClass<String>>` to a method that is expecting a `Group<? super BClass<?>>`.  That doesn't match, because although `AClass` is the superclass of `BClass`, `AClass<String>` isn't a supertype of `BClass<?>`.

The wildcards inside the parameters for `testExtends` and `testSuper` are to blame here.  Because you're assigning `AClass` and `BClass` to `T` in your instances, you can use them.  I can get this to compile if we change the declarations of these methods in `Group` to use `T`:

```
public void testExtends(Group<? extends T> value){}
public void testSuper(Group<? super T> value){}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what if call instGrB.testSuper(instGrB)? BClass<String> is a type of BClass<?>.

Comment: With my changes, that line now compiles.

Comment: yes, it compiles:) Question is why it don't compile with instGrB.testSuper(instGrB), if BClass<String> is a type of BClass<?> ? Or itn't?

Comment: Java's generics are invariant.  That means that the type parameter must be an exact match unless wildcards are involved.  The wildcards handle the part about `AClass` and `BClass`, but there are nested generics involved, and the subtypes there must match.  The `? extends` part handles the nested generics, but the `? super` does not.